# Finding the number of nodes in a 2-3 tree in SML

Tags: tree, sml, treenode

I have a midterm coming up so I'm working on the practice problems. I'm not sure how to begin this one.

A 2-3 tree is a tree in which each non-leaf node may have either two or three children and all
subtrees of a node have the same height. If we ignore the condition on the heights of subtrees, we can make the following SML type definition:

datatype ’a twoThreeTree =
| Empty

| Binary of ’a * ’a twoThreeTree * ’a twoThreeTree

| Ternary of ’a * ’a twoThreeTree * ’a twoThreeTree * ’a twoThreeTree;

a.
Write a recursive function N that computes the number of nodes in a 2-3 tree.

b.
Write a recursive function ht that computes the height of a 2-3 tree. (In analogy with binary trees, make the height of the empty tree -1.

If anything, help with part a would be all I need. I think I could use what I learn from a) to do b).

Answer (score 0):

This should help with (a).

```
fun N(Empty)            = 0
  | N(Binary(_,x,y))    = 1 + (N(x)) + (N(y))
  | N(Ternary(_,x,y,z)) = 1 + (N(x)) + (N(y)) + (N(z))
```

We assume the number of nodes for Empty is 0 and for each of the other types of nodes, we count the node itself and the number of other nodes.

For b, instead of adding things together.  Think about how your define height of the following tree

```
         NODE
         / \
LEFT_TREE   RIGHT_TREE
```

If the `LEFT_TREE` has height `H_left` and the `RIGHT_TREE` has height `H_right`.  Can you express the height of the whole tree as a function of `H_left` and `H_right`? What if the tree had three children?

```
fun ht(Empty)            = -1
  | ht(Binary(_,x,y))    = ...
  | ht(Ternary(_,x,y,z)) = ...
```